# Gestionar el salto de línea con Multicell FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Hola estoy usando FPDF para generar un reporte

```
//Encabezados de la tabla
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 8);//Colocando letras en negritas
//$pdf->Cell(18, 10, 'Consecutivo', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
//$pdf->Cell(28, 10, 'Service Tag', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(28, 10, 'Service Tag', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(50, 10, 'Usuario', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 10, 'Diferencia 1', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 10, 'Diferencia 2', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 10, 'Falla', 1, 1, 'C', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 8);//Devolviendo valores de letra
```

Estoy usando Multicell ya que el contenido de algunos registros se desborda y da mal aspecto al reporte

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Ancho alto,borde,salto de linea justificacion relleno
    $pdf->multiCell(28,10,utf8_decode($row['servicetag']),1,'B',false);
    $pdf->multiCell(50,10,utf8_decode($row['usuario']), 1, 0);
    $pdf->multiCell(65,10,utf8_decode($row['dif1']), 1, 0);
    $pdf->multiCell(65,10,utf8_decode($row['dif2']), 1, 0);
    $pdf->multiCell(65,10,utf8_decode($row['falla']), 1, 1);
}
```

El problema es que la información la está imprimiendo de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que la información se distribuyera apropiadamente, y para esto me gustaría controlar el salto de línea de los registros, pero no lo logro, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Yo capturaria las posiciones X y Y y las regresaria despues de cada multicel, tambien gardaria la posicion Y mas grande para regresar todo a su ubicacion original

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $max_y = $y;
    $y = $pdf->getY();
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $pdf->multiCell(28, 10, utf8_decode($row['servicetag']), 1, 'B', false);
    $max_y = $pdf->getY() > $y ? $pdf->getY() : $y;
    $pdf->SetY($y); // regresar a fila anterior
    $pdf->SetX($x + 28); // regresar a columna anterior mas espacio de la columna

    $y = $pdf->getY();
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $pdf->multiCell(50, 10, utf8_decode($row['usuario']), 1, 0);
    $max_y = $pdf->getY() > $y ? $pdf->getY() : $y;
    $pdf->SetY($y); // regresar a fila anterior
    $pdf->SetX($x + 50); // regresar a columna anterior mas espacio de la columna

    $y = $pdf->getY();
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $pdf->multiCell(65, 10, utf8_decode($row['dif1']), 1, 0);
    $max_y = $pdf->getY() > $y ? $pdf->getY() : $y;
    $pdf->SetY($y); // regresar a fila anterior
    $pdf->SetX($x + 65); // regresar a columna anterior mas espacio de la columna

    $y = $pdf->getY();
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $pdf->multiCell(65, 10, utf8_decode($row['dif2']), 1, 0);
    $max_y = $pdf->getY() > $y ? $pdf->getY() : $y;
    $pdf->SetY($y); // regresar a fila anterior
    $pdf->SetX($x + 65); // regresar a columna anterior mas espacio de la columna

    $y = $pdf->getY();
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $pdf->multiCell(65, 10, utf8_decode($row['falla']), 1, 1);
    $max_y = $pdf->getY() > $y ? $pdf->getY() : $y;
    $pdf->SetY($max_y + 10); // regresar a la posicion Y mas grande mas el alto de la fila
    $pdf->SetX($x + 65); // regresar a columna anterior mas espacio de la columna

    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Tambien es necesario poner atencion especial en caso que tus datos causen un salto de linea